# Deal with Email Delivered Notification in Application

Tags: .net, asp.net, email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I'm looking for a way to deal with delivered notifications in an ASP.NET application.
Basically I want to send an email with a delivery receipt, receive the delivered notification and then update my database to note that the email was actually received.

I'm in a closed environment - in that the emails in question are only sent internally to manager and other internal users, all using exchange - in the process of upgrading to Exchange 2007.

Whilst I can do some assumption, in that I can deal with ASP.NET throwing no exceptions when I send the email, however I want greater reassurance that the email has been delivered, so that if I don't receive a delivered notification then I can attempt to resend if a delivered notification hasn't been received within a certain period.

MOVED To : 
[Receive Email Notification (Exchange 2007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407637/receive-email-notification-exchange-2007)

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: Why would you want to do this in ASP.NET? It's a request/response architecture, not suited to deal with notifications. You want a Windows Service for that.

Comment: OK so any advise on where to look for this?  You're of course write, really what I'm after is a way to update my database with the receipt - web dev. is my game, but Windows Service does seem the way to go, would this be on the exchange server itself?

Comment: Where to look for what? Do you know how Exchange deals with notifications? Are you familiar with the Exchange API?

Comment: No not at all, I'm mainly a ASP.NET developer, though I have created Windows Services for Integration. Googling now...

Comment: Right, but what is it that you need help with?

Comment: How does Exchange deal with notifications, is there a database I can query? Do I have to deal with files? Or can I simple use a particular api to tell me if an email has been delivere?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3417/discussion-between-duncan-and-john-saunders)

Comment: I think you need to ask a separate question that asks, "How can my program receive a delivery notification from Exchange?"

Comment: as another option in case anyone is interested, there's a cloud based email service that gives you such functionality. http://sendgrid.com/  (I have nothing to do with them)